# Installing Solr on Windows 10

Tags: java, solr, lucene

Hi I'm a fairly new programmer whos trying to install Solr on Windows 10
i download Solr from  `http://mirror.fibergrid.in/apache/lucene/solr/6.2.1`

The only two requirements are a Solr release and Java 1.8 or later. I have installed Solr, and also verified my java -version to see what my java version is, which is 1.8.0_60.
I have went to the `solr/solr/example` folder, which looks fine. Then I use `java -jar start.jar` I am facing below issue:

```
Unable to access jarfile start.jar
```

Why is this doing this? My java version is as up to date as it says it should be?

Comment: Is the file `start.jar` present in the directory where you're trying to run it?

Comment: navigate to solr folder and open command prompt enter `bin/solr start`  .check here `https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr`

Comment: @jony I think your approach only works on Solr verison 4, I tried different approach and it's working for me, let me know If it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I will explain the approach on Widows 10 for solr-6.2.1:**

Navigate to the solr-6.2.1 file and see whether you have below contents?

```
C:\Users\userName\Downloads\solr-6.2.1\solr-6.2.1\bin>ls
init.d                   oom_solr.sh  solr      solr.in.cmd
install_solr_service.sh  post         solr.cmd  solr.in.sh
```

Once you see `solr` you can smile :) and try this!!

```
C:\Users\Shivasai\Downloads\solr-6.2.1\solr-6.2.1\bin>solr start
Waiting up to 30 to see Solr running on port 8983
Started Solr server on port 8983. Happy searching!
```

After this you just have to access solr in bowser by localhost://8983

Answer (score 1):

I hope your problem is resolved but still if anyone trying to use Solr on Windows then I followed below steps for Solr8.5.2 -

1. Download the binary zip file of required version.
2. Unzip the file.
3. First do basic check if you can start Solr server -
   a) Go to solr-8.5.2\bin in command prompt
   b) Type **solr -help**, then use **solr start**
   c) If you can see the help contents & server is starting, by default it will be on port **8983**
   d) now trying accessing its web page via **http://localhost:8983/solr/#/**
   e) If you see everything till now then congratulations, your initial test is passed.
4. Now let us add environment variables on Windows machine & same you can do to your Linux/Unix machine also -
   a) Add **solr_home** with value **<\path>\solr-8.5.2\server\solr**
   b) Add **<\path>\solr-8.5.2\bin** in **path** variable
5. Now you can execute solr commands in your command prompt without giving full path to Solr directory.
   I don't think command is **java -jar start.jar**, rather use **solr start** to start the Solr server.
   Hope it helps.

Comment: This was the solution for me using Solr 8.11 . Allow me to add upon this, solr start wasn't working for me at first because i was using GIT Bash, after switching to Powershell, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You probably downloaded the source version, which doesn't include the start.jar file, try this one:
http://mirror.fibergrid.in/apache/lucene/solr/6.2.1/solr-6.2.1.zip

Comment: It does include the start.jar file but the way to make it start is a bit tricky on solr 6. The approach for solr 4 and solr 6 seems to be different.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps for setting up the **Solr 7.4 (With SQL Server as data source)** and explore the features of solr.

1. Download the solr 7.4 distribution from the below link

   https://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/7.4.0/
2. Extract the Solr distribution archive to your local home directory, for instance say F:\solr-7.4.0
3. After extracting the solr distribution zip file, the folder structure would be like F:\solr-7.4.0..
4. Download the Java Jdk 8 and install the jdk.
5. After installing the jdk, jdk and jre will be installed in the path C:\Program Files\Java.. (as shown in the screenshot below).
   [image]
6. Also, make sure the java.exe file is present in the path C:\Program Files(x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\bin.. (Screenshot below)
   [image]
7. Environment Variables Change for Javapath setup:-
   Create variable with name ‘Path’ under ‘User variables’ section if not already exists.If variable with name ‘path’ already exists under ‘User Variables’ section , select the variable ‘Path’ and click ‘edit’ and add the entry ‘C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\bin’ (Screnshot below).
   [image]
8. Similarly, Create variable with name ‘JAVA_HOME’ under ‘System variables’ section if not already exists. If variable with name ‘JAVA_HOME’ already exists under ‘System Variables’ section , select the variable ‘JAVA_HOME’ and click ‘edit’ and add the entry ‘C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath’ (Screnshot below).
   [image]
9. Make sure the ‘apache-solr-dataimporthandler-..’,’mssql-jdbc-..’ and ‘sqljdbc42’ jar files are present in the location ‘F:\solr-7.4.0\solr-7.4.0\contrib\dataimporthandler’ (Screenshot below). These files are used for extracting the data from sql server database
   [image]
10. Open the ‘solr.cmd’ command file under ‘F:\solr-7.4.0\solr-7.4.0\bin’ search for the text ‘log4j2’ and set the LOG4J_CONFIG path as below. (Screenshot also attached below).
    set “LOG4J_CONFIG=file:///%SOLR_HOME%\server\resources\log4j2.xml”
    [image]
11. Note:- (imp) If we don’t set the log4j2.xml path as above in the step 9, we will get the exception as shown below when we start the solr. Don’t forget to configure the step 10.
    [image]
12. Now navigate to the bin folder of the solr (F:\solr-7.4.0\bin) and run the below command. (screenshot below)
    Solr start
    [image]
13. You can now see the solr is running on port 8983. Now, open the browser of your preference (say edge) and type http://localhost:8983/ and you should see solr running. (screenshot below).
    [image]
14. You can also run solr at different port number if needed. (say 80). To do this, navigate back to command prompt and run ‘solr stop -all’. This command will stop all the running instances of solr. Now run ‘solr start -p 80’. (this command will run the solr instance in port 80) (screenshot below).
    [image]